# Why are Vim 8 :term colours with gvim different from those in plain vim :term or bash?

Tags: gvim, terminal, bash, color

Vim 8 `:term` colours in `gvim` happen to be different from those seen in plain `vim :term` or `bash`.

How come? How does one obtain the same `bash` colours in `gvim`?

**EDIT:** I have been reading a bit more about [Using GUI color settings in a terminal](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_GUI_color_settings_in_a_terminal), but applying these plugins do not seem to change anything.

My main issue with `gvim :terminal` is that it is employing a dark blue on a black background, both for the directory in the command prompt and the headers of `dfc`.

[image: blue on black in gvim terminal]

If only I could get a handle on that dark blue in `gvim :terminal`, that would solve my issue.

Comment: Colours in `vim` and `bash` [**are determined by the terminal emulator**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158421/39845) one is using. The question that remains is: **What determines the `:terminal` colours in `gvim`?**

Comment: `:h g:terminal_ansi_colors` and related documents